# Active pivot DrillThrough header aliasing and specify on runtime which column to be extracted

Tags: activepivot

Anyone did this, aliasing the header name in the drillthrough and also specifying which column to be extracted during runtime.

The reason is every user has specified set of column to be displayed in the drillthrough.

Some example is really great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

for header aliasing this could be done by overriding the QueriesService if you do not use AP Live, then when you execute the DT you add your own aliasing there.

If you want this to be per user then do this in a user context, see the sandbox for instance we implemented there a ReferenceCurrency which is a bespoke context. In your case you'll imlement the same logic but that context will deal with the aliasing.

When a DT query is fired you intercep it in QueriesService get the context for the user and apply the aliasing that has been defined for that user, think about keeping a default aliasing if nothing is defined for instance.

Regards,

Comment: I will give this a try, I'm looking at the DrillthroughPostprocessor I thought that is the approach you are going to recommend. Thanks :)

Comment: you mean PostProcessedColumns ? that is used to add new attributes to the DT. If you want to give each user his own config the solution is to rely on a context.